# React-Native Symbol Iterator error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have started to get a new error while developing my current project. I have noticed that the error only occurs on Android and I have tried most of the solutions out there.

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_.keys(resultingStyle)[typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator"]()')
```

So this is the error.  I have already tried the coreJs solutions and the es6-symbol solutions but I still get the same error.

```
import 'core-js/es6/map'
import 'core-js/es6/symbol'
import 'core-js/fn/symbol/iterator'
```

and/or

```
import 'es6-symbol/implement'
```

Does anyone have any ideas please?